# Set() method is retrieving values but get() method instantiated in another class is returning null

Tags: java, android-activity, constructor, null, getter-setter

please could you help me with this?
Because it was working well until yesterday and now i simply don't know what happened, i already revised the whole code several times.
I have 3 classes, one is the main class which i've setted the variables and methods (getters and setters).
Another is a class which contains a method to set parameters from database and it's working well i already tested with logs.
The last one is a class which the Object is finally constructed to get the parameters from the second class.

Let me show you these codes.

Class number one:

```
public class Somewhere {
    private String place;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private Integer Status;

public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}
public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}
public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}
public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}
public Integer getStatus() {
    return Status;
}
public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.Status = status;
}
}
```

Method from Class number two:

```
public class sDao extends Dao {
    public sDao(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public Somewhere somewhereByStatus(String wherearg, String Status) {
    Somewhere s = null;
    openDB();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("select * from tb_somewhere where " + wherearg + "= '").append(Status).append("'");
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sb.toString(), null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        s = new Somewhere();

        s.setPlace(cursor.getString(1));
        s.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2)));
        s.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)));
        //until here this is working, i've already tested with logs.
    }

    closeDB();
    return s;
}
}
```

Main from Class number three:

```
String place;
Double latitude;
Double longitude;

String status = 10;
try {
        sDao x = new sDao(getBaseContext());
        Somewhere r = new Somewhere();

        r = x.somewhereByStatus("Status", status); //this is working until now

            place = r.getPlace(); // this is returning null but it has values
            latitude = r.getLatitude(); // this is returning null but it has values
            longitude = r.getLongitude(); // this is returning null but it has values

    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: first update String status="10" then run it again.

Comment: Don't use a while loop if you have a method that returns a single object. In the loop where you say it works it changes "s" to a new value but probably does another iteration and overrides it. Just remove the while and call moveToNext only once to get the first result.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        s = new Somewhere();

        s.setPlace(cursor.getString(1));
        s.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2)));
        s.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)));
        //until here this is working, i've already tested with logs.
if (cursor.moveToNext())    
{
    closeDB();
    return s;
}
}
```

Comment: your code might be not be sending the right reference. agree with  @user5222128

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by replacing cursor loop code like

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        s = new Somewhere();

        s.setPlace(cursor.getString(1));
        s.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(2)));
        s.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)));
        break;
    }
```